# Definition of adjoint functor and locally small categories

Tags: category-theory

In the definition of an adjoint pair of functors, is it implicit that the categories are locally small? I have searched for ages, and nowhere is this stated as an assumption, but the definition seems to require it. (Where we take the definition in terms of Hom isomorphism, for example here: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+functor )

Comment: Usually categories are defined to be locally small.

Comment: But no, there is no need for the categories to be locally small for the definition of adjoint functors to make sense. If you want to deal with non-locally small categories then there is no reason to force adjoint functors to be defined on locally small categories (obviously)

Comment: Most of the time, people consider non-locally small categories only temporarily: for example, one constructs a category and then does some work to conclude that it is in fact locally small (this happens most frequently, I guess, when one does localization in categories) This is done by constructing some other category somehow and showing it is equivalent to the original one. For that equivalence to make sense, you need yo allow functors between non locally small categories!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Is there a way of extending the notion of a hom-functor to non-locally-small categories so that the hom-isomorphism definition can be extended?  I think the OP is principally interested in the use of hom-functors in the hom-isomorphism definition (which require local-finiteness).

Comment: One can define functions between proper classes.

Comment: @Hayden Indeed that was my concern. @ Mariano Suárez-Alvarez ; So are you saying we replace the bijection of sets: HomD(L(c),d)≃HomC(c,R(d)), with a bijection of proper classes, and the definition still works?

Comment: You need to make precise what exactly you mean by «works»...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another way of stating an adjunction without referring to hom-sets, due to Lawvere (I think).

A functor $F \colon \mathcal A \to \mathcal B$ is left adjoint to $G \colon \mathcal B \to \mathcal A$ if and only if there exist an **isomorphism** of categories $\left(F \downarrow \mathrm{id}_{\mathcal B} \right) \stackrel \phi \simeq \left( \mathrm{id}_{\mathcal A} \downarrow G \right)$ between the [comma categories](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/comma+category) making the following diagram commute:
$$
\begin{matrix} 
  \left(F \downarrow \mathrm{id}_{\mathcal B} \right) 
  & \stackrel \phi {\large\simeq} 
  & \left( \mathrm{id}_{\mathcal A} \downarrow G \right) \\
  \hskip 20pt \searrow & & \hskip -20pt \swarrow \\
  & \mathcal A \times \mathcal B & 
\end{matrix}
$$
This definition makes sense even if the categories are not locally small.

Comment: This is actually the same as the hom-set definition. The fibres of the the two functors are the hom-sets, and the fact that $\phi$ is a functor corresponds to naturality of the bijection.

Comment: @ZhenLin Of course it is the same, the goal is to retrieve the usual notion of adjunction, not a new one. But this form allows no to care about the size of the hom-set, while the direct hom-set definition needs you to deal with the codomain of functors $\mathcal A^{\mathrm{op}}\times\mathcal B \to ?$.

Comment: Well, obviously. But my point is that this is just the direct translation of the hom-set definition into the language of two-sided fibrations.

Comment: @ Pece. Thanks! This actually makes it clearer. I've only just started learning category theory so hadn't come across comma categories yet.

Answer (score 1):

The unit/counit definition of an adjunction works for categories which are not locally small.

In fact, the notion of an adjunction may be defined in an arbitrary $2$-category, see [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjunction#definition).

We don't need Hom-sets. On the other hand, as stated in the comments, you may also work with Hom-classes to describe adjunctions between categories which are not locally small.

*Notice.* In many books categories are assumed to be locally small by definition. There are various reasons for this, but I guess this is not the best place to explain all of them.